# Form won't submit after jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have found this [jQuery validator](http://formvalidator.net/index.html). I use a jQuery code to submit the form once.

The validation works perfect. When an input field is not correct and I press the Submit button it gives an error and won't submit.

Then I will change the input correctly and the form won't submit.

Validate: `$.validate();`

Submit once

```
$("#form").submit(function() {
    $(this).submit(function() {
        return false;
    });
    return true;
});
```

Comment: When you submit the form and `return false;` you're instructing the form to **not** submit.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet causes the form to not submit:

```
$(this).submit(function() {
   return false;
});
```

Try this:

```
$('#form').validate();
```

Comment: So I need to replace $.validate();

Comment: The code from the second code chunk -- replace your entire provided validated code with that. It should do the work for you. What rules are you trying to apply to your fields?

Comment: But, after I have changed that will it also check if the form is submitted multiple times?